# Build failed with an exception: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I have problems with the execution of the project, I just downloaded the project from git but it seems that it doesn't work with the version of my Android Studio. The project was created with the 27 SDK compile version of Android.

I have tried a lot of different solutions but nothing had worked. This are the things I had already tried:

1. Change the compile version

Change the `compileSdkVersion` to `28`

2. Set the dexOption to false to libraries

Add the dexOption for the libraries

```
dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
```

3. Execute the `androidDependencies` test of the gradle and it is build succesfully.

Like I said nothing of these had worked, but I found an issue running the build test.

[image]

And the test gave me this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

So this are my graddle files:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-28'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myIdApplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.1@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.hendraanggrian:recyclerview-paginated:0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    implementation 'bg.devlabs.fullscreenvideoview:library:0.0.8'
    implementation 'com.github.halilozercan:BetterVideoPlayer:1.2.alpha1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'

}
```

I have google this issue for days, and nothing worked.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repo ?

Comment: I had found the problem and its with a library that its having problems with the SDK `28`, now im searching how to correct this error, but thanks for the interest.